# There is / There are

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, there-is, premodifiers

I believe it well established that the choice of whether to use "There is" or "There are" with the phrase "a lot of" depends on the following word. For example, you would say:

1. There **is** a lot of wine.
2. There **are** a lot of cars.

What is the right form to use for ***a pair of, a bunch of, a group of,*** etc.?

Comment: Related: *[Should I say “there is a handful of…” or “there are a handful of…”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58676)*, *[How to choose verb after “there” in beginning of sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33393)*, *[“There’s” or “There are”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77089)*, *[There is/are one or several apple/~s?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40669)*, *[“There are so many” vs. “There is so many”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8854)*, and many others.

Comment: Since _There_-Insertion is usually optional, one can usually recover the base sentence, where it may be easier to determine the verb agreement; but this is a strictly existential use, where _There_-Insertion is obligatory. You can say _A lot of cars **are** in the parking lot_, though, and ***is*** would sound very strange here.

Comment: Whichever one sounds good to your ear in that context that it is in. But if you in skool, then you put down what the teach wants you to put down--that is, the "correct" answer.

Comment: *I believe it well established that the choice of whether to use "There is" or "There are" with the phrase "a lot of" depends on the following word.* -- Well, that's partially right. The part that's right is that the number of the noun phrase "a lot of X" does depend on what X is. But, since the example is a clause in the form of an ***existential construction***, the construction type will be the major factor here, and also the context.

Comment: I think it depends on whether the phrase is an intensifier or has semantic significance of its own: compare *a lot of new recruits have come in today!* which simply remarks on the sheer number of new recruits, and *a lot of new recruits has come in today!* which implies that a lot, being a specific number of new recruits, has recently arrived.

Answer (score 2):

You question is basically the last sentence of your post:

"What is the right form to use for a pair of, a bunch of, a group of, etc.?"

I think the answer to this is a bit complicated, as it depends on the way the speaker/writer is thinking about the noun phrase.  Is it in essence a singular entity, or in essence a plural entity?  Thus, the examples given by previous posters are correct, but they each represent a different way of thinking:

The example given by Goos, "There is a bunch of bananas hanging from the tree," is clearly a singular entity being spotted by someone looking at it as such.

The example given by Michał Kosmulski, "there are a bunch of people outside," is different in that it is the people who are the real item here, not the bunch.

Thus, I would say that it is the focus of the speaker/writer which is the essential element here.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question. To leave constructive criticism or to clarify a question (or answer), earn the reputation required to [comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 1):

In English, expressions such as "a bunch of", "a couple of", "a lot of", etc. are handled as a plural form would be, so you say "there **are** a bunch of people outside". The form matches *people* (of which there are many) and not the singular *bunch*. The same would go for "there are a million reasons to do something" - it's plural because of the *reasons*, not singular because of the single *million*.

"A pair of" is more tricky. In the common meanings of "two related objects", or its use with [plurale tantum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum), you would use singular: there **is** a pair of doves on the roof, there **is** a pair of glasses on the table. However, in the less common meaning of "a few" / "a couple of", you would use plural, so for example: there are a pair of pencils on my desk.

Comment: What's the subject in the OP's example? . . . Besides that, there's *"A lot of wine is in that bucket."*

Comment: “There are a bunch of people outside”, _but_ “There is a bunch of grapes/flowers on the table”, with a similar distinction as _pair_ (literal vs. non-literal sense).

Comment: "A pair of doves" is *plurale tantum*? Are you sure?

Comment: @JoeZ. He didn’t say that. ‘Glasses’ is a plurale tantum; ‘a pair of doves’ is just “two related objects”.

Comment: Oh. Whoops, I misinterpreted that. Still, I have heard people say "there are a pair of doves" before.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer to date.  However, I would have been more convinced had the author said "trickier" rather than "more tricky."

Comment: I've never heard 'pair' used to mean 'a few'. 'A couple', yes, but never 'a pair'.

Answer (score 0):

for a pair of:

There is a perfectly nice pair of shoes in your collection.

a bunch of:

They are a good bunch of people.
There is a good bunch of kids in the school.

a group of:

There is a group of teens who help the poor.

Comment: Your example for *a bunch* is a bit misleading, as it doesn't conform to the application to dummy pronouns throughout the rest of the thread.

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am being too specific, but I would like to point out that wine is a "non-countable" item that is measured in specific units, i.e. There is a lot of wine vs. There are many bottles of wine, or several glasses of wine.  Just as you could say "there are two bowls of rice, that is a lot of rice".

Answer (score 0):

There is still a lot of time.

There are still seconds remaining on the clock.

My theory is that "are" makes it sound more educational, yet in this sentence I used "is" to describe the amount of "sophistication" the word creates.

So therefore to sound less of a high school student, per se, I would rewrite it to state:

There are many theories to the usage of "are" and "is". The theory that I would state is that using "are" creates a higher level of sophistication in the construction of an English sentence.

I remember college professors telling me to stay away from "is" because it starts to deteriorate the sentence potential. How I love that I listened to them but always seemed to  show that I wasn't paying attention. :D

Bad grades don't equal bad people. I guess I was trying to demonstrate the contrary to popular belief.

Answer (score -1):

This has to do with countable vs uncountable nouns. Wine is a tricky example here, because it has two plurals meaning two different things. *A lot of wine* could refer to a large volume of wine, where *a lot of wines* refers to a large selection.

Let's try **sand** vs **rocks** to make it more clear cut.

> There is a lot of sand

We say this because sand is an uncountable noun. It would be insanity to try to figure out exactly how many grains of sand there are in a given pile, which is why the term *grain of sand* exists in the first place. Sand is inherently plural, but you couldn't say ***there are a lot of sand*** because that implies there is a fixed number. However,

> There are a lot of rocks

Here (not counting gravel), you can ascertain in a finite amount of time just how many rocks you're talking about. Because it is possible to determine the number, it is a count noun, and as such is pluralized with **are**.

---

**Edit for relevance**:

As with *a lot of*, some other words denoting a generalized plural have to be decided on a case by case basis. It typically has to do with whether grouping the object creates a new object per se, e.g. *there **is** a bunch of grapes over there* vs *there **are** a bunch of cats in the other room*.

Others, though, refer to either a fixed amount or are a noun in and of themselves, e.g. *a pair of* or *a group of*, respectively. These are treated as a single unit.

Comment: This is not what the question is about.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ah, I misread the question. I thought it was referring to quantities that would qualify as a bunch, a pair, etc., not the words in and of themselves.

Comment: If you want a better example of count/mass, try ***beans*** and ***rice***; they're both food products, about the same size, and are often cooked or served together; but they're in different English lexical categories. Check your favorite dictionaries to see whether they tell you that _a bowl of rice_ and _a bowl of beans_ are both grammatical, but that **a bowl of rices* and **a bowl of bean* are both ungrammatical.

Comment: @JohnLawler Brilliant. I've found that people take more readily to examples involving food (at least, the people I've dealt with) and that's a very simple, elegant contrast.

Comment: @JohnLawler What's the difference between _sand and rocks_ and _rice and beans_ ? (apart from what sauce you'd put on them)

Comment: @Frank memorability of the analogy

Comment: But for "formal" subject-verb agreement, doesn't the verb agree in number with the subject? So what is the subject in the OP's example?

Comment: @F.E. It all comes back to the ideas of countability and definiteness. Formal vs informal has nothing to do with it, here.

Comment: Er, well, first of all, what is the grammatical subject of the OP's sentence?

Comment: @F.E. Which one? If you're referring to the *There is/are* sentences, ***there*** is a [dummy pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) and the subject of the sentence.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to any of the existential clause examples. "There" is the grammatical subject, because of subject-aux inversion: ***"Is there*** *a lot of wine?"* . . . And so, shouldn't the subject-verb agreement be between the verb and subject?

Comment: @F.E. I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Do you agree with me that "subject-verb agreement" is between the grammatical subject and the verb?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14633/discussion-between-andy-and-f-e).

Comment: Unfortunately, "chat" doesn't work on my account. *[shrugs]*

Comment: Yeah, their "chat" doesn't let me in. Which is also kinda a good thing, so I don't waste, er, spend too much of my time in there. :)

Comment: I don't like the chat, either, so I can just tell you that you're both expecting `Subject` to be a unitary property hanging on one NP in a sentence. Nope, no such luck; in English every syntactic rule uses its own set of properties to define the "subject". Auxiliary inversion picks whatever's there, referential or dummy; so does Raising. But verb agreement is governed by semantic considerations in addition to syntactic ones, so it typically chooses the chômeur subject _a lot of cars_ to agree the verb with. There are a lot of "subject" properties that usually overlap, but don't always.

Comment: @JohnLawler I mentioned up in my answer that it really has to be taken on a case-by-case basis. In this case, the form of plurality depends on not just the N in the NP but also the Det, and AdjPs can modify it as well. English is fun!

Comment: Like I said, semantic considerations. And it is fun, isn't it?

Comment: Nope. I'm expecting ***subject*** to be a grammatical function in a structure, where in this case the structure is a clause. Auxiliary inversion picks the grammatical subject for its inversion with the auxiliary, and that is why it is a useful diagnostic tool in identifying the grammatical subject of a clause. Using semantic considerations in the way suggested is similar to traditional grammar's way of classifying categories of words as nouns, adjectives, verbs, etc, and which ends up giving us noun-y clauses, adjective-y nouns, etc.--which is, of course, a mess.

Comment: @F.E. What's so messy about nominals? x-bar theory makes them trivially easy to parse.

Comment: "*Nominals*"? You talking about the head of a noun phrase, right? :)

Comment: @F.E. No, I'm talking about nominals, words and phrasal units that aren't technically nouns being used as a noun. The noun to adjectival's adjective, or adverbial's adverb.

Comment: Oh, so a phrase that is the subject of a clause is considered to be a "nominal"?

Comment: Assuming that your answer was yes to my previous comment . . . Then I guess the phrase *"Under the mat"*, which is the subject in the clause *"Under the mat isn't a very sensible place to leave the key"*, would be considered to be a nominal, even though it is obviously a preposition phrase. So, if a phrase functions as the subject or object of a clause, then that phrase is a nominal?! Hmm, it seems that category and function seem to be getting all tangled up, a lot like what traditional grammar did or still does. -- yes, yes, I'm procrastinating and staying up way too late.

Comment: @F.E. Yes, because, in that case, *Under the mat* is the subject of the sentence, it is classified as a nominal. I suspect posting a question about it would provide more thorough, informative answers than this comment section, especially because it is so OT. :)

Answer (score -2):

The subject of "there is" would always be a singular entity, as is a "pair" or a "bunch",  while the subject of "there are" would always be a plural entity, as is "there are 'apples'". "There are" could not refer to a "pair" or a "bunch", which are, by definition, singular entities.

A "bunch of" or a "pair of" anything is always a singular entity, regardless of whether  is a collection of discrete objects or a continuous amount of something, because it is "the bunch" or "the pair" that determines the plurality or singularity of the subject, not the subject itself.

Comment: There are (not ***is***) a bunch of things wrong with this answer.