# Is it "Most of the reading was done" or "Most of the reading were done"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I wrote a blog post, which has the below sentence.

> I owned a few paperback books, but most of the reading was done on my
>   15.6-inch laptop screen.

[Grammarly extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammarly-spell-checker-g/kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen?hl=en) pointed out an error with this statement.

It told me to replace ***was*** with ***were***. It gave me the following explanation.

> *The singular verb was does not appear to agree with the plural subject most. Consider changing the verb form for subject-verb
>   agreement.*

I somehow feel ***was*** is the right word here, but don't know why.

I need your help folks. Can you please tell me which is right and why?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think what **grammarly extension** says is correct? You should **never trust** any on-line spell and grammar checker. They can't tell the difference between countable nouns and non-countable nouns or between singular nouns and plural nouns. Related question, [“Most of what” and “is” or “are”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195862/most-of-what-and-is-or-are)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of something noncountable or continuous is singular:  most of the house is carpeted; most of the summer is hot; most of the milk is bad; most of the public is undecided (US English).

But most of the items that are countable are plural:  most of the rooms in the house are carpeted; most summer days are hot; most of the cartons have spoiled; most of the public are undecided (UK English).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Will Briggs. So, what's the answer in this case? I think that since reading isn't countable, I should use 'was'. What do you think?

Comment: Yes:  "Most of the reading was done."