# “What I saw was…” vs “What I saw were…”

Tags: verb-agreement, auxiliary-verbs, clefts, what-clefts

Someone says I need to use "was", someone says to use "were". Which one is correct?

> What I saw were a driver and an attendant.

or

> What I saw was a driver and an attendant.

Comment: *Was* is more natural here. *What* is usually singular, and so it sets the brain up to expect the singular verb *was.*

Comment: @Anonym "What *were* you doing?" "What were their names?" Hmm... not sure if I agree with your analysis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusing rule about subject-verb agreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195849/confusing-rule-about-subject-verb-agreement)

Comment: If it was an individual sighting, then _what I saw (on Tuesday) was ..._ If it were two separate sightings then _what I saw (on Tuesday, then on Friday) were_ ... I think it is a conceptual matter (in this case).

Comment: @Mari-LouA In your first example *what* is the object and in your second the complement. *What* must be the subject in order to force singular agreement. You're right that my initial analysis was lacking.

Answer (score 4):

When you start with "What", you're referring to an incident or object that you've seen. So it seems more appropriate to use the pair **what** ... **was**
 like you were answering a question **What was it that you saw?**
So say it like this:

> **What** I saw **was** a driver and an attendant.

But you could indicate that you're referring to the people and say it like this:

> **The ones** I saw **were** a driver and attendant.

Comment: Devil's advocate here: and if the subject was "we" would you still say  *"What we saw was a driver and an attendant"*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes, it seems correct to use it like "what we saw was..."

Comment: I remember seeing a [similar question on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/139963/what-we-saw-was-were-plural-noun-v-ing), the most upvoted answer seems to suggest that either "was" or "were" would be acceptable.